# Subset sum algorithms, their time complexity

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

The algorithm is in Python. Seems correct to me, ideas how to prove it? And what would be its time complexity?

```
from bisect import bisect

# Implements the decision version of subset sum.
# The subset sum problem: given a set and a number find a subset of the set which sums to the given number.
# Inputs: an ordered list of integers xs, and an integer n which is the target sum.
def subset_sum(xs, n):
    if n < sum(filter(lambda x: x < 0, xs)):
        return False
    if n > sum(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, xs)):
        return False
    xs = xs[:]
    u = {}
    def rec(i, n):
        if not (i, n) in u:
            u[i, n] = False
            k = bisect(sums[:i], n)
            while k > 0:
                k -= 1
                u[i, n] = u[i, n] or sums[k] == n
                u[i, n] = u[i, n] or rec(k, n - sums[k])
        return u[i, n]    
    sums = xs
    return rec(len(sums), n)
```

It has been answered below that **the above algorithm is exponential time**.

That being so, I have a follow up question: Is the algorithm still exponential time if the rec sub-routine above is changed into the following?

```
def rec(i, n):
    if not (i, n) in u:
        u[i, n] = False
        k = bisect(sums[:i], n)
        k -= 1
        if k >= 0 and n >= sums[0]::
            u[i, n] = sums[k] == n or rec(k, n - sums[k]) or rec(k, n)
    return u[i, n]
```

The recurrence $T(i, n) = T(i - 1, n - 1) + log_2(i)$ is what I came up with for worst case running time. Maybe that's far off.
But from that it seems it is $|S|log(|S|)$.

New information:
I have been able to solve a problem instance involving a set of 8192 integers equal to the range (1, 9, ... 65537) and the target n = 65525 in one and a half minute on my laptop. The resulting list consists of 125 integers. That makes the algorithm (with the above changes applied) sub-exponential, certainly not $2^{|S|}$ . The time taken is for the search version which applies the decision version discussed here $|S|$ times.

Here is a link to the full source code of my test set-up:

http://codepad.org/5s5lkHAm

Comment: What's your question?  I don't see a question here.  (Also, note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics and pseudocode in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.)

Comment: It is really hard to understand what your algorithm is supposed to do. Is there any meaning to the answers it finds? It seems like pre-calculating all sums would be a good idea (something that may make your algorithm linear in time). Also, you can get different answers depending on the order in which you try different values for `i`. Eg. you can first look for whether there is a sum equal to `N` and only after that try to do other manipulations on `N`... In other words, do you need to know the complexity of this algorithm, or maybe algorithm can be altered to work faster?

Comment: Thanks for the edit to explain what your question is.  Now that I can see what your question is, have you looked at [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755)?  (possible dup?)  Also are you aware that subset sum is NP-hard?  It is unlikely that you have found a polynomial-time algorithm for subset-sum, so you should be asking yourself whether that algorithm is correct.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the np-hardness and of the unlikeliness of a exact polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: I think the algorithm only works for non-negative integers, but this is not really a problem because such problem instances can be transformed into an instances of positive integers.

Comment: The range of integers you used in your experiment is far too small to trigger the worst-case running time. You need to try a carefully constructed instance where the integers are just "right", for example an instance created by reduction from a 3-SAT formula that encodes integer factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is very similar to exhaustive search. It is basically the following approach:

> In order to check whether some subset of $S$ sums to $n$, go over all $i \in S$ and check whether some subset of $S \setminus i$ sums to $n - i$.

The actual algorithm uses memoization and a few other optimizations. Its complexity is exponential in the size of $S$ (probably roughly $2^{|S|}$ in the worst case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a subset sum problem. This video explains a DP solution to the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6FhG--P7z0

Comment: Welcome! We discourage answers that contain nothing but a link because links often go out of date, which just leaves a blank answer. Please edit your answer to include al the necessary information: the link is fine as a source and somewhere to go for more information but it shouldn't be the whole answer, please.